# como sacar datos de un arreglo de JavaScript e insertarlos en una consulta PHP uno por uno en diferentes inserciones

Tags: php, javascript, html, json, array

buenos Dias programadores tengo una duda quisiera que me ayudaran con algo 
tengo el valor almacenado de cantidad que lo almaceno dentro de cantid=[]; 
y despues esos datos con un json los llevo a una consulta en PHP los valores que no son arreglos no son problemas porque los saco y los inserto pero los valores que son en arreglo tendria un problema al insertarlos y quisiera que me ayudaran a insertarlos con un for

```
function usu(){
    var persona=document.getElementById("persona").innerHTML;
    var lista=document.getElementById("lista");
    var pedido=document.getElementById("lista-pedido");
    var radioid;
    var cantid=[];
    var produc=[];

    if(lista.childNodes.length>1){
        var tamaño=lista.childNodes.length;
        for(var i=1; i<tamaño; i++){
            var mesa=lista.childNodes[i];
            var radio=mesa.childNodes[1];
            if(radio.checked){
                console.log(radio.value);
                radioid=radio.value;
            }
        }
    }
    if(pedido.childNodes.length>1){
    var tamaño2=pedido.childNodes.length;
    for(var i=1; i<tamaño2; i++){
        var mesa2=pedido.childNodes[i];
        cantid.push(document.getElementById(mesa2.id+"-1").innerHTML);
    }   
    }    

    if(pedido.childNodes.length>1){
        var tamaño3=pedido.childNodes.length;
        for(var i=1; i<tamaño3; i++){
            var mesa3=pedido.childNodes[i];
            produc.push(mesa3.value);  
            produc.console(mesa3.value); 
        }   
    }     

    var prueba=511;
    var usu=document.getElementById("usu").innerHTML;
    $.getJSON("./json/ingresar.php", {prueba:prueba, usu:usu, radioid:radioid}, 
    function(resulta){
        var valor = JSON.stringify(resulta);
        console.log("lo que se supone que tiene valor " + valor);
    });
}
```

Forma que los ingresa dentro de la *base de datos*:

```
<?php
include '../Conexion_DB.php';
$c = new Conexion_DB();
$conn = $c->__constructor();
$id = $_GET["prueba"];
$usu = $_GET["usu"];
$radioid = $_GET["radioid"];

if($conn){
    $sql = "insert into Ventas_Cuentas (Cuenta, Usuario, Mesa) 
values(".$id.",'".$usu."','".$radioid."')";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    echo json_encode('jaló', JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
} else {
    echo json_encode('no me conecté :(');
}
?>
```

Los datos de radioid y de usu y prueba no tengo problema pero los que necesito ayuda son los de cantidad y produc

gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si bueno. en realidad no es problema. Aunque mejor envialos por post por el tamño de los datos.

```html
$.ajax({
        let arr=JSON.stringify(cantid)//aquí guardas como STRINGIFY el contenido del arreglo
       url: './json/ingresar.php',  
       dataType: 'JSON', 
   data:{prueba:prueba, usu:usu, radioid:radioid,'cantid':arr},
                cache: false,                    
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(resulta)
    {
                var valor = JSON.stringify(resulta);
        console.log("lo que se supone que tiene valor " + valor);
        
                }
 });
```

Luego el PHP trabajas la variable" $_POST['cantid'] "  y la consideras un array.

Espero haberme explicado. Saludos

Comment: gracias funciono segui usando getjson pero entendi la idea y funciono

Comment: Que bueno, que te haya funcionado. Si, con GET te funciona, pero  cuando envias un volumen importante de información, se suele utilizar POST. La razón entre otras es que puede que en producción el servidor limite el tamaño de las URL que recibe.  En tu caso si el "array cantid" llega a tener una cuantiosa cantidad de datos, es posible que muchos de ellos no se envien. 
(igual todo eso lo puedes configurar en el PHP.ini)   Saludos.